# Calling Powershell from MATLAB does not move to next line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, powershell, command, command-prompt

I have a command that calls powershell using !powershell . it works fine but, the first command will execute a publishing of data action from an external program and does not proceed to next line of code in MATLAB until there is a subscriber to the published data. the problem is that the next line of code is the one that subscribes to the published data so it just runs for ever waiting for the data. any ideas how to make the code continue? I have tried the continue statement but since I have called powershell, it stays there and MATLAB commands do not get executed. Also, I have tried to run the commands backwards, so subscriber first and publisher after but get same issue. Any ideas?

```
pubPath = 'powershell -inputformat none cd path' ;
subPath = 'powershell -inputformat none cd path2';

[status_one,publish] = system(pubPath);
[status_two,subscribe] = system(subPath);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start the job in the background, such that PowerShell returns immediately before the job finishes. Note that it is PowerShell that waits for the job to finish, not MATLAB.

End the PowerShell command with an ampersand (`&`) to run it in the background:

```
[status_one,publish] = system('powershell -inputformat none cd path &');
```